# Is this the correct definition for the standard topology in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, definition

Is this the correct definition for the standard topology in $\Bbb R^2$;

$T_{st}=\{(x_1,y_1)\times(x_2,y_2)|x_i,y_i\in \Bbb R\}$

Comment: What does $T_{st}$ stand for?

Comment: What is meant by $T_{st}$? The collection can indeed be recognized as a subbase of the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$ (which is the product topology). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @drhab $T_{st}$ for standard topology ,sorry I thought this was standard notation. So you say it can be seen as a subbase ?, what is the actual definition of the standard topology on $\Bbb R^2$ ?

Comment: @drhab I thought it was the standard topology because of here on page 2 http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~matsumura/math4530/Intro%20to%20Topology%20week%202.pdf

Comment: It is no topology since it is not closed under unions. It is a **basis** of the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb R$ be equipped with its usual topology.

For $i=1,2$ there are projection functions $\pi_i:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\mapsto x_i$.

Then the product topology is the smallest topology such that the projection functions are continuous.

Demanding this comes to the same as demanding that the product topology is the smallest topology such that sets of the form $(a,b)\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\times(a,b)$ are open sets.

Also it comes to the same as demanding that the product topology is the smallest topology such that sets of the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ are open sets. This corresponds with the collection mentioned in your question and this collection serves as a subbase and also (more strongly) as a base of that topology.

Be aware though that this collection is not a topology itself. For that note that e.g. the union $(0,2)\times(0,2)\cup(1,3)\times(1,3)$ is not an element of the collection, so the collection is not closed under unions (hence is no topology).

Further it can be proved that this product topology is the same as the topology that is induced by the metric: $$d(\langle x,y\rangle,\langle x',y'\rangle)=||\langle x,y\rangle-\langle x',y'\rangle||$$

The topology described is commonly labeled as "standard topology" on $\mathbb R^2$.